# Can there be more than 1 secret room per level?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I've only ever found a single secret passageway. Can there be more than 1? Can there be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TotalBiscuit, in his ["WTF is" youtube serie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dg6GLRtiSFA) (~12min30), had a chamber with 2 secret rooms , so
yes there can be more than 1 secret room.

I don't know if there can be 0.

Comment: I had a map for a particular floor and it showed no secret rooms, so 0 is also possible.